# ng-admin: Can editionView only update the changed fields

Tags: ng-admin

I want to update only the changed fields of entity,but the editionView of ng-admin transport all fields,even unchanged.How can I only transport the changed fields or get the changed fields?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can't do that except if you override FormController.submitCreation by using Angular decorator.